# VCS incremental elaboration feature

Tags: system-verilog, synopsys-vcs

Does anyone knows this feature? I came across this term, and not sure this is not the same as  incremental compilation (below)

```
....
4 modules and 0 UDP read.
        However, due to incremental compilation, only 1 module needs to be compiled.
....
```

If this is not it, are there any special switches for that, or does that work automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This is partition compile flow.
Use this option during elaboration: -partcomp=modautopart
First time compile take longer time, but subsequent compile will be faster depend on which module/package being modified.

Answer (score 0):

Incremental compilation is the default mode in VCS. VCS will analyze only the units which changed since last elaboration, but on elaboration VCS will re-elaborate the whole design.

From VCS User guide:

During elaboration, VCS MX builds the design hierarchy. By default, when you recompile the design, VCS MX compiles only those design units that have changed since the last elaboration. This is called incremental compilation.
The incremental compilation feature is the default in VCS MX. It triggers recompilation of design units under the following conditions....

Partition compile is a different VCS feature in which VCS pre-elaborate smaller partitions, and in the last elaboration stage VCS "combines" the smaller pre-elaborated partitions to one.